# Router configuration does not switch the pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why this router configuration does not navigate to '/1/abc/home/inbox'?
No errors/warnings in console.

Didn't find an answer in router docs.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/:id/:name/home" component={Home}>
        <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

This code navigates to inbox correctly by link above:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/:id/:name/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/:id/:name/home/inbox" component={Inbox}/>
</Router>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your routes seem to be ok. I have a local test setup exactly like this, and it works. Does your home component display props.children correctly?

Comment: I can also confirm that this work as expected. Could you define `does not navigate to` for us?

Comment: Answer is below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, my miss. I forgot to render {this props.children} in Home component.

Thank you **0xRm**, **Elod Szopos**.